# Syntax for query where all words in field must be present in query

Tags: solr

How would I form a query where all of the words in a field must be present in the query (but possibly more). For example, if I have the following words in a text field:
"John Smith"

A query for "John" should return no results

A query for "Smith" should return no results

A query for "John Smith" should return that one result

A query for "banana John Smith purple monkey dishwasher" should return that one result

Comment: How query "banana Smith John purple monkey dishwasher" should work?

Comment: That's what I'm asking - how do I make a query such that all words in the field are required in the query, but more are allowable.

Comment: Strange use case - usually docs are much longer than the number of keywords in search. You are trying to do the reverse. So do you want a document with field as `banana purple monkey dishwasher` rank even higher for your search query `banana John Smith purple monkey dishwasher` than simply `John Smith`?

Comment: I'm not overly concerned with the rank, just that it matches or not, the essential criteria I need is "all words in document must be contained in query for query to match at all"

Comment: @EJ01, my questions was: does order or word matters?

Comment: Word order does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DismaxQueryParser(dismax) / Extended DisMax Query Parser (eDisMax) with a smaller value of "mm"(minimum match) parameter.

By default "mm" set to 100% i.e. all query token should be matched in a document for considering the document as a hit. "mm"=10% implies minimum 10% of query tokens should match in a document for considering it as a hit.

For configuring "mm" you can have look [here.](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DisMaxQParserPlugin#mm_.28Minimum_.27Should.27_Match.29)

You can also find details about "mm" [here.](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/util/doc-files/min-should-match.html)

Comment: I don't think that's what I want though, MM determines how many query tokens should be matched in a document, and I don't care about that. I only care that the query contains all of the words from the document (and possibly more); but not that all words in the query are present in the document.